# npx create-react-app myapp generates FETCH_ERROR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at http://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser reason: 
Unexpected number in JSON at position 80754
```

nothing work for me
node version = v15.13.0
npm version =  7.7.6

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem I cleaned my npm cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

To verify if your npm cache is cleaned you can use

```
npm cache verify
```

and then try running

```
npx create-react-app (Your App Name)
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because your system looking for dependencies on the wrong URL.
I hope this work for you :

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at http://registry.npmjs.org/create-hmac reason: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 715